# Android Problems with Clickable TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, textview, clickable

So, an explanation of my app first: the main activity is supposed to call a second activity, which then implements a fragment in order to display details about a list item clicked. All of this seems to be going okay, but within the new activity/details window, there's a TextView that the user should be able to click in order to change from 'finished' to 'not finished' and vice versa. Right now the new fragment loads, but it doesn't seem to recognize interaction from the user. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity implements ListSelectionFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener, View.OnClickListener {


private boolean finished=FALSE;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListSelectionFragment detailFrag = ListSelectionFragment.newInstance(displayMode, position, page);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.item_frame, detailFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    findViewById(R.id.item_frame).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
    textView1.setText(displayMode);

    if(finished==TRUE) {
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.completebtn);
        textView2.setText("Finished");
        textView2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }

    TextView completeBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.completebtn);
    completeBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.completebtn);
    textView.setText("Finished");
    finished=TRUE;
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare the variable `finished`? And click where to change from finished to not finished.

Comment: Sorry, I cut that part out... I defined it as a boolean variable for the class (right below the first line in the snippet above)

Comment: Unless I am miss reading the code it looks like it will stay "finished". Also I don't see where you are adding the onClick listener to the textview

Comment: Which TextView are you talking about? There are many TextViews.

Comment: @snowCrabs I set the code up to stay finished for now, in order to simplify things. The variable initializes to FALSE, so the question is why clicking it in the app isn't working to change it to TRUE.

Comment: @MaihanNijat I'm specifically referring to the textview for which the onclicklistener is being set

Answer (score 1):

Set click listener on your TextView to catch the click.

For example:

**First register the event listener on your TextView.**

```
textView1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**And once the event (click) is happened and do the following:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    finished=TRUE;
}
```

**Update:**

Replace following which you have `onCreate`:

```
if(finished==TRUE) {
  TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.completebtn);
  textView2.setText("Finished");
  textView2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
}
```

With:

```
textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.completebtn);
      textView.setText("Finished");
      finished=TRUE;
      TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.completebtn);
      textView2.setText("Finished");
      textView2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
   }
});
```

**Note:** I suggest to use `setOnFocusChangeListener` instead `OnClick`. Get the content of the TextView and if it's filled or correct then change the background colour because if user click on `TextView`, the background will change, even without having content.

Here is the code:

```
textView1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
       // Put your code here, what you want to execute.
   }
});
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have the setOnClickListener placed in the onCreate() method... Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you check if finished is true in the on create method, this, however will only get checked at the start of the program, two options you have are:

- Check if it is finished in a loop in a separate thread (VERY BAD OPTION)
- run a method from the onclick method and from the oncreate method (only if it is true)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by 'run a method from the onclick method'. Shouldn't I be able to run whatever code is needed from within the onclick method? I've tried creating a separate method, without much result.